# Can anyone recommend a cheat sheet for the Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

It would be a plus if you are recommending it because you used it yourself.

Comment: http://www.hyperslug.com =)

Comment: Learn PowerShell instead (really: it is far more powerful and consistent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Download this http://www.sans.org/security-resources/sec560/windows_command_line_sheet_v1.pdf
- And go here go  [here](http://technet2.microsoft.com/WindowsServer/en/library/44500063-fdaf-4e4f-8dac-476c497a166f1033.mspx?mfr=true)
- Some common DOS and Linux commands  [here](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-6.2-Manual/getting-started-guide/ch-doslinux.html)
- List of all DOS Command Line [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DOS_commands)
- Another good  [site](http://www.techtalkz.com/blog/tips-n-tricks/list-of-all-dos-commands.html)
- [Good DOS Command Index](http://www.easydos.com/dosindex.html)
- A good DOS command Reference. You can download it  [here](http://joncamfield.com/oss/schooltools/Reference/DOS.PDF)
- Micosoft Command-line reference A-Z in Windows XP. Go  [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Do you use any of these sites yourself? If so, which ones are your favourite?

Comment: I use Micosoft Command-line reference A-Z in Windows XP.

Answer (score 4):

At some point I printed the entire overview page at http://ss64.com/nt/.  It's great for quickly finding the command I want to use, then I actually go to the web page if I need more info on usage.

Comment: I've found the forum there also very good, for help on more complex commands and scripting.

Comment: The webpage looks like a nice reference, but it isn't as well designed as a lot of printable cheat sheets

Comment: @Casebash: true... however I've found that the cheat sheets I print up rarely get used because I'm always connected to the internet.  So just having the overview is enough for me, though you're right it's not pretty and not that in depth :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a cheat sheet in the normal sense but I often type

`help`

to get a list of available commands and then

`help command`

to get the command's usage and arguments.

It's always available so I never lose it.

Comment: I think it would be better to get used to typing 'command /?' instead, as that also works with non-default command line programs. 'command -h' is common with linux ported programs.